# Microsoft Edge not loading CSS files with activated Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, iis, microsoft-edge, windows-authentication, internal-server-error

I'm creating an intranet website and using the ASP.NET MVC template with Windows Authentication. After compiling and logging in with my credentials, the CSS hasn't loaded.

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015. Everything works fine in Internet Explorer 11. I've not written one line of code in this brand new project but Edge doesn't load the CSS. Moreover, it seems like the problem only appears with activated windows authentication as a login method. I've created some new projects with no login method and with the custom user account method and it all works fine in Edge. Why is it not working with windows authentication in Edge?

So basically what happens is I see the raw site without the styles. I opened the developer tools and saw that the bootstrap.css and the Site.css file weren't loaded. I tried to open the path in Edge and I got a 500.0 Internal Server Error. Again Internet Explorer does his job.

See this picture to see the website and debugger
[Home page with debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMUcF.png)

Here is the internal server error:
[Internal Server Error 500.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdIpK.png)

Sorry for the German version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you're using Windows Authentication I'm assuming this is an enterprise environment. Any chance there are group policies in place on Edge that are blocking things? Happens all the time at my job unfortunately.

Comment: You got a 500 error for a CSS? That's weird because it's a static file. Can you temporarily turn off the authentication and see if it goes away?

Comment: If you turn off custom errors you might get more info in the error message

Comment: @gilliduck yes I'm working in an enterprise environment and I'm struggling often with restrictions. But I'm not sure why it's working perfectly fine with Internet Explorer and Firefox but not with Edge.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've disabled the authentication temporary and it works. I also looked up the network tab in the developer tools with activated windows authentication and it says I'm unauthorized to load bootstrap.css and site.css. Pretty strange because I can login to the site and it recognizes me.

Comment: So... we know it's a permissions issue. Here's one thing to try: https://forums.asp.net/t/2060963.aspx?Windows+Authentication+Prevents+CSS+From+Loading You should probably check folder permissions inside IIS also and see if it's any different

Comment: Try to check Static content option is enabled in 'Turn Windows features on or off' settings. If it is not enabled than try to enable it and again make a test to see the results. https://i.postimg.cc/LXNFZqy1/172.png also you need to provide IUSR to read permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you guys for your help!

I've finally figured out what was causing the problem:

Our lovely group-policy in my company blocked some certificates. I'm able to load the solution on our server and run it on IIS and not on IIS Express. Everything works fine there. Unfortunately we are restricted to change the security tab in internet options so I can not add localhost to the trusted websites.

Again, thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I googled for hours and tried so many things without success.
Finally I found a working solution for me and so I thought I'd share it.

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015.

In the project configuration file [SolutionFolder].vs\config\applicationhost.config
I changed from this:

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
    <providers>
        <add value="Negotiate" />
        <add value="NTLM" />            
    </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

to this (changed order and enabled windows authentication):

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <add value="NTLM" />
        <add value="Negotiate" />        
    </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

Maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: Awesome. Got VS 2017 here, works here as well. Do you have an explanation as to what this does, by any chance?

Comment: (Although, for me, I didn't have to set enabled to true)

Comment: @Calculuswhiz, Unfortunately, I cannot explain this in detail. I was surprised that it worked for me as Edge seems to favour Negotiate as the authentication mechanism. The first provider is used as default and the second as a fallback. Maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 1):

I tried every recommendation like...

.vs\config\applicationhost.config

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
    <providers>
        <add value="NTLM" />
        <add value="Negotiate" />
    </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>

<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9227:ComputerName" />
</bindings>
```

CMD

- netsh http add urlacl url=http://**ComputerName**:9227/ user=everyone

Set Startup URL in VS 2015:

- Servers = IIS Express
- Project URL = http://**ComputerName**:9227/

That worked for some time, but after a Win 10 update to a newer build, I had the same problem as described above: Windows Authentication, ASPX is loaded but not CSS and JS

Solution (but not really answered the question): **Changed to Edge Chromium**... There everything works fine :-)
I suggest this as a solution since Edge is at the end of its life cycle anyway.